# Which of these approaches is better for a conditional event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want my Button component to only handle `onClick` events if a callback function is passed to the component. I have two approaches for this, but I do not know which approach is better.

**Approach 1** - Bind `handleClick` with `this.handleClick` or `false` in the constructor, and pass `handleClick` to `onClick` in the render method.

```
class Button extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    onClick: PropTypes.func
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    onClick: undefined
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = (props.onClick) && this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;

    onClick();
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <Wrapper onClick={this.handleClick}> // False if onClick is undefined
        {children}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

**Approach 2** - Bind `handleClick` in the constructor and pass `handleClick` or `false` in the render method.

```
class Button extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    onClick: PropTypes.func
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    onClick: undefined
  };

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;

    onClick();
  }

  render() {
    const { children, onClick } = this.props;

    return (
      <Wrapper onClick={(onClick) && this.handleClick}>
        {children}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a matter of preferences since both cases are almost equal.

1. If you choose *Approach 1* you would be saving space in memory *(conditionally)* because `this.handleClick` would be a small value for cases in which `props.onClick` is `undefined` or `false`, **in the second approach** you would be always setting the function which takes a little more space (however, this space is depreciable for me).
2. *Approach 2* is more commonly used, people usually binds the function in the constructor without any condition and validates the call in the property that's needed.

Just as a side note, there is a third approach you could use which is to [define an arrow function](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render) in the `onClick` prop, I don't really use this one that much but just wanted to mention it.

You can learn more about [passing functions to components in react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)